# How to query database to obtain a list where each value is the sum of the number of records with a the same date value?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am performing a query on an SQLite database using SQLAlchemy. I'm doing a four table join. One of the fields within one of the tables is a datetime field. I am able to obtain the list of tuples with all records that fit the criteria I'm looking for. What I want to obtain is a list that contains the sums of records with the same date. So if I had 1 record with a certain time, 3 records all with the same time but different from the first, I would obtain the list [1, 3].

Here is my current query:

```py
rework_records = DB.session.query(ReworkRecord, NonConformanceRecord, Part, Product).join(
        NonConformanceRecord, NonConformanceRecord.id == ReworkRecord.nonconformance_id
        ).join(
            Part
            ).join(
                Product
                ).filter(
                    Product.id == form.product_family.data).order_by(
                        desc(NonConformanceRecord.entry_date)
                        ).all()
```

This returns the list of tuples with each entry having records from each of the four tables being joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only missing a `GROUP BY` statement. The expression `COUNT(*)` will provide the number of records with the given entry_date.

```
rework_records = DB.session.from_statement('''SELECT NonConformanceRecord.entry_date, COUNT(*) 
FROM ReworkRecord 
JOIN NonConformanceRecord ON NonConformanceRecord.id == ReworkRecord.nonconformance_id 
JOIN Part
JOIN Product
WHERE Product.id == form.product_family.data
GROUP BY NonConformanceRecord.entry_date
ORDER BY NonConformanceRecord.entry_date DESC''')
```

I'm not too familiar with the way you wrote it, but I believe it would just be:

```
rework_records = DB.session.query(NonConformanceRecord.entry_date, COUNT(*)).join(
        NonConformanceRecord, NonConformanceRecord.id == ReworkRecord.nonconformance_id
        ).join(
            Part
            ).join(
                Product
                ).filter(
                    Product.id == form.product_family.data).group_by(
                        NonConformanceRecord.entry_date).order_by(
                            desc(NonConformanceRecord.entry_date)
                        ).all()
```

The top one should do the exact same thing in the case that this second part didn't work. However, I don't know where you get `form.product_family.data` from as you dont join a table called `form`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I didn't see your answer before I ended up just post-processing the results of the query that I posted (creating a dictionary structured like {date : [(record tuple)]} and then looping through the query results and adding to the dictionary). Then I got the amount of records for a given date just by doing len([(record_tuple)]). Also converted the date from a datetime object to a formatted string so that there would actually be records with the same 'date' because the datetime objects were specific down to the millisecond.